# In a user's reputation data, what does "User Removed" mean?

Tags: support

When I checked my reputation data recently, I noticed that, in addition to entries like "accept", there was a little message that said "User Removed."

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that a user got deleted or requested deletion.

As a result, any vote you received from that user gets lost.